# ¿Cómo se puede cambiar el tamaño de un array?

Tags: java, array

Tengo un programa en java donde quiero almacenar nombres de personas en un array, y no acabo de lograr hacer que cada vez que se introduzca una nueva persona (al elegir case 1 en el switch) el array varíe de tamaño:

```html
int sumaPersona=0;
String personas[];
personas = new String [sumaPersona];

do {
                switch (menu = menu()) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Nombre de persona");
                    nombre=stdin.readLine();
                    
                    for (int i=0; i<personas.length; i++ ){
                        personas[i]=nombre;
                        sumaPersona=sumaPersona;
                        sumaPersona++;
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println("Muestro nombres de personas "+Arrays.toString(personas));

                break;
                
                // El resto de opciones del menu no las he pegado para que no sea tan largo 
                
                } while (menu != 0);
    }
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: no necesitas un array, necesitas una lista.

Comment: es un ejercicio de clase, me han pedido un array, como se podría hacer?

Comment: tendrías que crear un nuevo array más grande, y copiar los datos del array anterior ahí. pero insisto, un array no es recomendable si no sabes que tamaño tendrá, es mil veces mejor una lista.

Comment: No puedes cambiar el tamaño de un array una vez creado, quizá lo que se requiere en el ejercicio es que uses un `ArrayList`, pues de otro modo sería un proceso complicado para un principiante, aparte de que no es una práctica para nada habitual crear un array y luego, de forma dinámica, tener que modificar el tamaño del mismo.

Comment: ¿No será que te estás complicando demasiado y el ejercicio consiste en guardar nombres en un array, teniendo en cuenta que este tiene un límite y no vamos a meter infinitos nombres, solo por aprender a guardar datos en un array? ¿Dice que tiene que crecer de tamaño con cada nombre? Entonces tiene que ser otro tipo de dato que no es un array `[ ]`

Comment: ¿Cambiar el tamaño de un **Array** en Java? No se puede. Usa un **ArrayList** en su lugar.

Answer (score 17):

> > ¿Cómo se puede cambiar el tamaño de un array?

La respuesta es un **NO**. En Java no se puede cambiar el tamaño de un arreglo.

Pero antes de explicar el porqué, necesitamos tener claro que significa ***cambiar el tamaño de un arreglo.***

Miremos la siguiente imagen:
[image: diagrama de memoria]

**Fuente:** https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/the-realloc-function-in-c/

En la imagen tenemos al principio un arreglo de 5 elementos de tipo `integer` pero luego se quiere aumentar 6 espacios de memoria en el arreglo. Entonces, cambiar el tamaño de un array simplemente significa aumentar o disminuir la cantidad de espacios de memoria que tiene un arreglo. En nuestro bloque de memoria de arriba se está aumentando el tamaño del arreglo de `5` a `11` elementos, sin embargo, se conservará el mismo bloque de memoria siempre y cuando después del último elemento del arreglo no haya un espacio de memoria ocupado, ya que si eso llegara pasar se debería de reservar un nuevo bloque de memoria y luego se tendría que copiar los elementos del bloque antiguo al nuevo.

Ya, ... **¿Para que rayos mencioné todo lo anterior?**

Porqué para lograr cambiar el tamaño de un arreglo se necesita de una función/rutina que pueda aumentar o disminuir la cantidad de elementos de un bloque de memoria. En Java no existe tal método, sin embargo, en otros lenguajes de programación como lenguaje C, si tiene tal función y se llama [realloc](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdlib_h/realloc.php).

**¿Por qué en Java no se puede cambiar el tamaño de un array?**

Porqué no tiene una función como [realloc](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdlib_h/realloc.php), de lo contrario, si se pudiera redimensionar un arreglo.

También recalco que muchas personas creen que redimensionar un arreglo significa crear un nuevo arreglo y copiar los elementos del anterior arreglo en el nuevo, sin embargo, eso es incorrecto. Un gran ejemplo es el método [Resize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.8) de C#, cualquiera pensaría que redimensiona un arreglo, pero en realidad no es así, hace el mismo procedimiento que había mencionado anteriormente. El nombre del método es engañoso.

**Redimensionar un arreglo** significa cambiar el tamaño del arreglo pero conservando el mismo bloque de memoria (donde están alojados los elementos del arreglo).

Ahora, una **solución sencilla** para poder registrar nombres de personas sin preocuparnos del tamaño del arreglo, es usando la clase [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) y de este modo, podrás crear una lista de objetos de tipo `String`.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String namePerson;
        List<String> listPerson = new ArrayList<String>();
        int op;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre:");
            namePerson = sc.nextLine();
            listPerson.add(namePerson);
            System.out.println("Desea salir? Presione (-1)");
            op = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();//para limpiar el buffer stdin
            if(op == -1)
                break;
        }while(true);
        for(int i = 0; i != listPerson.size(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(listPerson.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

La clase `ArrayList` la implementaron a través de un vector/arreglo dinámico, esto quiere decir, que cuando creas un objeto de tipo `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> listPerson = new ArrayList<String>();
```

En realidad el constructor de esta clase se encarga de crear el arreglo dinámico con una capacidad inicial (código fuente de [ArrayList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)) de `10` elementos, esto nos dice que internamente esta clase tiene la referencia de un arreglo para X elementos pero que aún no tiene ninguna referencia de un objeto (por esa razón si el método [size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()) se llegara a ejecutar debería de dar como resultado `0` elementos).

Sin embargo, la clase `ArrayList` no aumenta el tamaño del arreglo dinámico donde está almacenada las referencias de cada objeto, por lo tanto, cuando la cantidad de objetos supere la capacidad máxima de la lista, lo que pasará es que se reservará memoria para un nuevo arreglo, en la cual se copiará los elementos del bloque antiguo en el nuevo bloque de memoria.

Entonces si tu profesor no te dejara usar la clase `ArrayList`, podrías crear tu propia clase en la cual se encargue de emular la implementación de un `ArrayList`.

Por ejemplo:

```
class ArrayPerson
{
    private String[] person;
    private int capacity;
    private int count;

    public ArrayPerson()
    {
        person = new String[10];
        capacity = 10;
    }

    public ArrayPerson(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        person = new String[capacity];
    }

    //Obtiene la cantidad actual de objetos reservados en el arreglo
    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    //Para obtener la referencia donde está el arreglo por completo
    public String[] getPersons()
    {
        return person;
    }

    //Para obtener la referencia de X objeto de tipo String del mismo arreglo
    public String getPerson(int index)
    {
        return person[index];
    }

    //Inserta una referencia de un objeto de tipo String en el arreglo
    public void add(String refPerson)
    {
        ++count;
        if(count > capacity)
        {
            capacity += 10;
            person = Arrays.copyOf(person, capacity);
        }
        person[count - 1] = refPerson;
    }
}
```

Básicamente esta clase cuando la llegues a instanciar, te da la oportunidad de ejecutar un constructor parametrizado o por defecto.

Si ejecutamos el constructor parametrizado:

- Creará un arreglo de objetos con un tamaño que dependerá del valor que tenga el parámetro del constructor.

Si ejecutamos el constructor por defecto (sin parámetros):

- Creará un arreglo de objetos con un tamaño predeterminado (con una capacidad inicial máxima de `10` elementos).

Ahora viene la parte más interesante, el método `add`. Este método básicamente se encargará de añadir una referencia (dirección de memoria) en X posición del arreglo de objetos, sin embargo, cuando la cantidad de objetos supere la capacidad máxima del arreglo, se calculará una nueva capacidad y se usará el método [copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) de la clase `Arrays` y lo que hace este método es reservar memoria para un nuevo arreglo de objetos, en la cual copiará los elementos del bloque antiguo en el nuevo bloque de memoria y lo que retorna este método es la referencia de un objeto de tipo `String[]` en la cual internamente estará la referencia del arreglo de objetos (con un tamaño de elementos ya actualizado).

La forma de usar esta clase sería de esta forma:

```
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String namePerson;
        //Instaciamos la clase ArrayPerson 
        ArrayPerson ap = new ArrayPerson();
        int op;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre:");
            namePerson = sc.nextLine();
            //Añadimos la referencia del objeto al arreglo
            ap.add(namePerson);
            System.out.println("Desea salir? Presione (-1)");
            op = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();//para limpiar el buffer stdin
            if(op == -1)
                break;
        }while(true);
        //Recorremos el arreglo con los elementos que tenga registrado el arreglo 
        for(int i = 0; i != ap.getCount(); ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(ap.getPerson(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**Conclusión:**

En Java no se puede aumentar el tamaño del arreglo, pero si se puede reservar memoria para un nuevo bloque de memoria en la cual copiamos los elementos del bloque antiguo en el bloque nuevo y para no estar haciendo este mismo procedimiento cada vez que se quiera insertar un nuevo elemento al arreglo, lo hacemos cuando la cantidad de elementos supere la capacidad máxima del arreglo (tal como lo hace la clase `ArrayList`).

**Recomendación:**

Siempre es bueno usar las clases que pertenezcan en la API de Java, debido a que, ahorra trabajo, sin embargo, para fines académicos, no estaría mal en implementar tus propias clases.

Comment: Excelente, muy detallada la explicacion

Comment: Increíble respuesta.

Comment: Es incorrecto afirmar que no se puede redimensionar por la falta de punteros, casi todos los lenguajes populares no manejan punteros y sin embargo pueden redimensionar arreglos.

Comment: @Sal He editado la respuesta para no traer falsas afirmaciones.

Comment: Saber el tiempo que te ha llevado escribir esta respuesta, genial! buena explicación :)

Answer (score 2):

Si bien es cierto que aumentar el tamaño de un array no es eficiente y hay mejores estructuras de datos para ello, la pregunta "Cambiar tamaño de array" se puede contestar con:

`System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)`

Tal vez sea una demostración del maestro para que se entienda mejor la diferencia entre varias opciones de programar este problema.

La manera de usar `arraycopy` es:

```
String[] personas = new String[1];
String[] nuevasPersonas;

personas[0] = "Victor";
nuevasPersonas = new String[personas.length + 1];
// los 5 argumentos de arraycopy son:
// arreglo_original, elemento_inicial_del_arreglo_original,
// nuevo_arreglo, elemento_donde_se_quiere_empezar_a_copiar_al_nuevo_arreglo,
// número_de_elementos_a_copiar
System.arraycopy(personas, 0, nuevasPersonas, 0, personas.length);

System.out.println("Muestro nombres de personas " + Arrays.toString(personas));
personas = nuevasPersonas; // poner el nuevo arreglo (con un elemento más) en la variable original
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu pregunta, aunque tu código tiene algunos problemillas por resolver todavía:

- Estás inicializando el arreglo `personas` con cero elementos: `personas = new String [0];`.
- El bucle `for` que tienes en `case 1` no es necesario.

Comment: es una buena opción, sin embargo me imagino que si está iniciando el maestro no quiere un método como este que ya hace las cosas. Supongo su ejercicio es para practicar bucles o algo por el estilo.

Answer (score 2):

Con este código puedes "aumentar" el tamaño de un arreglo mediante un auxiliar.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] personas = new String[0];
        int menu = 1;
        do {
            menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Eliga opcion", null));
            switch (menu){
                case 1:
                    String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba nombre", null);
                    String[] aux = new String[personas.length + 1];
                    for (int i = 0; i < personas.length; i++) {
                        aux[i] = personas[i];
                    }
                    aux[personas.length] = nombre;
                    personas = aux;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(personas));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } while(menu != 0);

        System.out.println("Terminó, las personas guardadas son: " + Arrays.toString(personas));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**No puedes cambiar el tamaño de un array puesto que al declararlo debes dimensionarlo.**

```
int sumaPersona=10;
String personas[];
personas = new String [sumaPersona]; //10 elementos
```

Si deseas almacenar nombres de personas, puedes hacer uso de un [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html),

```
//int sumaPersona=0;
//String personas[];
//personas = new String [sumaPersona];

List<String> personas = new ArrayList<String>();

do {
                switch (menu = menu()) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Nombre de persona");
                    nombre=stdin.readLine();

                    for (int i=0; i<personas.size(); i++ ){
                        //personas[i]=nombre;
                        personas.add(nombre);
                        //sumaPersona=sumaPersona;
                        //sumaPersona++;
                    }


                    //System.out.println("Muestro nombres de personas "+Arrays.toString(personas));
                    System.out.println("Muestro nombres de personas "+personas);
                    System.out.println("Total de personas " + personas.size());

                break;

                // El resto de opciones del menu no las he pegado para que no sea tan largo 

                } while (menu != 0);
    }
```

Te sugiero revisar la [documentaciòn oficial para que conozcas que mètodos puedes hacer uso al usar List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 1):

Usa el método estático `Arrays.copyOf( personas, personas.length+1)`, el cual hace una copia del arreglo original en un arreglo de tamaño distinto.

El aprender cómo lo hace internamente es la puerta de entrada a las **Estructuras de Datos**, y es invaluable!.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería utilizar una `List<String> personas = new ArrayList<>()`

Una vez quieras agregar una persona, simplemente utilizas la función propia de los `ArrayList` llamada `add` del siguiente modo `personas.add("Pepito")`

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con:

```
 string args[] = new string[8];  
 Array.Resize(ref args, args.Length + 1);
```

Comment: El consejo tendría más valor si muestras el código original editado. También sería bueno que explicaras la función resize.

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).