# Como rellenar un array dinamico

Tags: java, array

Hola estoy intentando rellenar un array dianamico. La cosa es que no sé como ir sumando indices dentro del array. Me entenderéis con el ejemplo. Yo hago un while que mientras el usuario quiera seguir introduciendo numeros no salga del while. Pero como introduzco el valor del numero en un array que inicialmente no se sabe cuantos espacios tendrá. Abajo del todo pongo cadena[]=numero; pues que pongo entre parentesi porque si fuera un for pondria "i" pero en este caso no puedo porque no se el cadena.lenght.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Metodos_E5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int cadena[]=null;
        int salida=0;
        int decision=1;
        while(decision==1) {
              System.out.println("Quieres declarar un numero? 1-Si 2-No");
              decision=sc.nextInt();
              if(decision==1) {
              System.out.println("Declara un numero :");
              int numero=sc.nextInt();
              cadena[]=numero;
              }else {
                  decision=0;
        }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Si no te dejan usar `ArrayList`, te toca implementar tu propio [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Obviamente no necesitas crear todos los métodos que tenga la clase, sino, los necesarios para resolver tu problema. En este enlace explico como funciona la clase `ArrayList`: [¿Cómo se puede cambiar el tamaño de un array?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323451/c%c3%b3mo-se-puede-cambiar-el-tama%c3%b1o-de-un-array/323823#323823).

Comment: Sino podes usar ninguna implementacion de List, o pones un top maximo (un array de 1000) o puedes declarar un array de no se 100 , y si se llega a la cantidad de 100 creas un array por el doble ,copias los primeros 100, borras el primer array y sigues usando el nuevo array a partir de la posicion 100. y asi al infinito.
internamente así es como funciona ArrayList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuándo no se concoe el número de elementos de una lista o colección a priori es mejor usar un [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) en Java e ir añadiendolos poco a poco, por ejemplo:

```
public class Metodos_E5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> cadena = new ArrayList<>();
        int salida=0;
        int decision=1;
        while(decision==1) {
            System.out.println("Quieres declarar un numero? 1-Si 2-No");
            decision = sc.nextInt();
            if (decision==1) {
                System.out.println("Declara un numero :");
                int numero=sc.nextInt();
                cadena.add(numero);
            } else {
                decision=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Los números introducidos son:" + cadena)
    }
}
```

Si existe alguna circunstancia que impide usar objetos como `List`, una solución con arrays sería así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] cadena = new int[100];
    int total = 0;
    int salida=0;
    int decision=1;
    while(decision == 1 && total < cadena.length) {
        System.out.println("Quieres declarar un numero? 1-Si 2-No");
        decision = sc.nextInt();
        if (decision==1) {
            System.out.println("Declara un numero :");
            int numero=sc.nextInt();
            cadena[total++] = numero;
        } else {
            decision=0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Se han introducido " + total + " números")
    for(int i = 0; i < total;i++) {
        System.out.println("Número " + i + ": " + cadena[i])
    }
}
```

Como el array debe tener un tamaño predefinido, se crea uno de 100 posiciones y luego se graba un número en cada una, si se llegara a rellenar los 100 numeros la aplicación terminaría (sale del bucle) para evitar una excepción.

Comment: entiendo pero te cuento, estoy estudiando y en clase aun no nos han explicado nada de es así que debería hacerlo sin usar ese método..

Comment: Ok, entiendo, adapto la respuesta entonces

Comment: Entiendo tu respuesta pero el único modo de hacer un array dinámico es List? porque tu respuesta sigue siendo un array estático de 100 posiciones osea que si quiero 100023023020 por decir un numero no podría. Y un array dinámico debería aceptar cualquier cantidad.

Comment: @winnie Los arrays en Java son dinámicos. No existe los arrays estático en dicho lenguaje. En otros como C, sí.

Comment: ya,pero le.llame de ese modo porque tengo que indicar el tamaño si no lo se.

Comment: @winnie Hace mucho di una respuesta a tu problema (es parecido): https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323451/c%c3%b3mo-se-puede-cambiar-el-tama%c3%b1o-de-un-array/323823#323823

Comment: @winnie, los arrays en Java (definidos con `[]`) hay que crearlos con un tamaño predefinido, si quieres algo dinámico (que crezca) hay que usar `List` u otro tipo de estructuras más complejas (Colas, Pilas, etc).