# ¿Como "redimensionar" un array sin arraylist?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando redimensionar un array de dos dimensiones para que se amplie cada vez que hay una linea en un fichero.txt. Como habria que modificar el metodo ampliararray para que se amplie unicamente las filas del array, es decir, las posiciones de la variable i. Con este código hay:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at examen.EjercicioCOVID.ficheroleer(EjercicioCOVID.java:32)
at examen.EjercicioCOVID.main(EjercicioCOVID.java:10)

Precisamente busco evitar eso, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
package examen;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



     public class EjercicioCOVID {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    int [][] casoscovid=ficheroleer("covid.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<casoscovid.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<casoscovid[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(casoscovid[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static int [][] ficheroleer (String ruta) throws FileNotFoundException{
    int [][] datos= new int[0][2];
    File archivo = new File (ruta);
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(archivo);
    int i = 0; //provincia (DIA=(PROVINCIA/5)+1)
    int j; //casos
    int provincia,dia,casos;
    while (leer.hasNext()) {
        provincia=leer.nextInt();
        dia=leer.nextInt();
        casos=leer.nextInt();
        datos=ampliararray(datos);
        j = 0;
        datos[i][j]=provincia;
        j++;
        datos[i][j]=casos;
        i++;
    }
    return datos;
}

public static int [][] ampliararray (int [][] arrayviejo){
    int [][] arraynuevo=new int [arrayviejo.length+1][arrayviejo.length];
    for (int i=0;i<arrayviejo.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<arrayviejo[i].length;j++) {
            arraynuevo[i][j]=arrayviejo[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return arraynuevo;
}

}
```

covid.txt. Provincia Dia Casos
1    1   25
2    1   60
3    1   120
4    1   3
5    1   6514
1    2   59
2    2   78
3    2   5
4    2   2
5    2   5
1    3   4
2    3   8
3    3   64
4    3   7
5    3   59
1    4   55
2    4   11
3    4   565
4    4   222
5    4   335
1    5   0
2    5   5554
3    5   661
4    5   1
5    5   4
1    6   666
2    6   7
3    6   7
4    6   7
5    6   7
1    7   7
2    7   4
3    7   1
4    7   2
5    7   58
1    8   7
2    8   87
3    8   889
4    8   445
5    8   22
1    9   44
2    9   33
3    9   77
4    9   44
5    9   88
1    10  11
2    10  444
3    10  777
4    10  44
5    10  222
1    11  777
2    11  111
3    11  777
4    11  7522
5    11  222
1    12  4242
2    12  41242
3    12  14144
4    12  1414
5    12  141414

Comment: En Java, los arreglos no se pueden redimensionar. Lo que tienes que hacer es lo mismo que hace internamente la clase `ArrayList`: crear un nuevo arreglo con la nueva capacidad ("redimensionado") y en este copias los elementos del viejo.

Comment: podrias mostrar como estan escritos los datos en el txt

Comment: Si pero en est asignatura no nos dejan redimensionar con Arraylist, el metodo ampliararray es para eso

Comment: Puestal cual indican en los comentarios. Recrear el array emulando lo que hace ArrayList

Comment: Tal como menciona @E.Betanzos no se puede redimensionar, lo que si se puede hacer es crear uno nuevo asignando la memoria necesaria para tener una nueva "capacidad". Te recomiendo leas esta respuesta que está muy completa https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/323823